# How to stream music using java as server?

Tags: java, stream, webserver, mp3

I am trying a simple java code for http,
if i use chrome with the file location (http://localhost:8888/somefile.mp3)
it works fine, but if i am using safari on the iphone, it is throwing error:
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
but if i use LAMP or any php server, it works fine.
how can I make it work with the java as well?

This is the http server:

```
package com.streamternet;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class HTTPServer extends Thread {

static final String HTML_START =
        "<html>" +
                "<title>HTTP Server in java</title>" +
                "<body>";

static final String HTML_END =
        "</body>" +
                "</html>";

Socket connectedClient = null;
BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
DataOutputStream outToClient = null;


public HTTPServer(Socket client) {
    connectedClient = client;
}

public void run() {

    try {

        System.out.println( "The Client "+
                connectedClient.getInetAddress() + ":" + connectedClient.getPort() + " is connected");

        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connectedClient.getInputStream()));
        outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());

        String requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
        String headerLine = requestString;

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(headerLine);
        String httpMethod = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String httpQueryString = tokenizer.nextToken();

        StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        responseBuffer.append("<b> This is the HTTP Server Home Page.... </b><BR>");
        responseBuffer.append("The HTTP Client request is ....<BR>");

        System.out.println("The HTTP request string is ....");
        while (inFromClient.ready())
        {
            // Read the HTTP complete HTTP Query
            responseBuffer.append(requestString + "<BR>");
            System.out.println(requestString);
            requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
        }

        if (httpMethod.equals("GET")) {
            if (httpQueryString.equals("/")) {
                // The default home page
                sendResponse(200, responseBuffer.toString(), false);
            } else {
                //This is interpreted as a file name
                String fileName = httpQueryString.replaceFirst("/", "");
                fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName);
                fileName="/"+fileName;
                if (new File(fileName).isFile()){
                    sendResponse(200, fileName, true);
                }
                else {
                    sendResponse(404, "<b>The Requested resource not found ....</b>", false);
                }
            }
        }
        else sendResponse(404, "<b>The Requested resource not found ...." +
                "Usage: http://127.0.0.1:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000/</b>", false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendResponse (int statusCode, String responseString, boolean isFile) throws Exception {

    String statusLine = null;
    String serverdetails = "Server: Java HTTPServer";
    String contentLengthLine = null;
    String fileName = null;
    String contentTypeLine = "Content-Type: text/html" + "\r\n";
    FileInputStream fin = null;

    if (statusCode == 200)
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\r\n";
    else
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" + "\r\n";

    if (isFile) {
        fileName = responseString;
        fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        contentLengthLine = "Content-Length: " + Integer.toString(fin.available()) + "\r\n";
        if (!fileName.endsWith(".htm") && !fileName.endsWith(".html"))
            contentTypeLine = "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n";
    }
    else {
        responseString = HTTPServer.HTML_START + responseString + HTTPServer.HTML_END;
        contentLengthLine = "Content-Length: " + responseString.length() + "\r\n";
    }

    outToClient.writeBytes(statusLine);
    outToClient.writeBytes(serverdetails);
    outToClient.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);
    outToClient.writeBytes(contentLengthLine);
    outToClient.writeBytes("Connection: close\r\n");
    outToClient.writeBytes("\r\n");

    if (isFile) 
        sendFile(fin, outToClient);
    else 
        outToClient.writeBytes(responseString);

    outToClient.close();
}

public void sendFile (FileInputStream fin, DataOutputStream out) throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] ;
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = fin.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        out.flush();
    }
    fin.close();
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

    ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (8888);

    System.out.println ("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 8888");

    while(true) {
        Socket connected = Server.accept();
        (new HTTPServer(connected)).start();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is not *streaming*, this is just a plain HTTP request-response conversation. Looking at your server, it seems broken in a number of ways that it's even difficult to tell why Chrome manages to download anything.

I put a [minimal HTTP server online](http://pastebin.com/mrrP3tiC), just for fun. It's far from complete, it's not configurable and only supports `GET` requests, however I think it's a good starting point if you don't want to rely on another server or framework. It can only give two kinds of responses: `200 OK` and `404 NOT FOUND`. Resources are searched on the CLASSPATH, and are sent to the client along with MIME type information based on the extension. You may want to add the MP3 MIME, but please note that's just a toy and is only meant to show the very basics of HTTP.

The code:

```
public class TinyHTTPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);

        while (true) {
            final Socket connection = server.accept();
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler();
                    handler.handle(connection);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public static class RequestHandler {

        public void handle(Socket socket) {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream(), "US-ASCII");
                String path = getPath(scanner.nextLine());

                Response response = find(path);

                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                for (String header : response.headers) {
                    out.print(header);
                    out.print("\r\n");
                }

                out.print("\r\n");
                if (response.url != null)
                    writeEntity(response.url.openStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                out.print("\r\n");

                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private String getPath(String requestLine) throws IOException {
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("GET (/\\S*) HTTP/1\\.1").matcher(requestLine);
            matcher.find();
            return matcher.group(1);
        }

        private Response find(String path) {

            if (path.equals("/"))
                path = "/index.html";

            Response response = new Response();
            URL url = RequestHandler.class.getResource(path);

            if (url == null) {
                response.headers.add("HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND");
            } else {
                response.url = url;
                response.headers.add("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

                String type = "application/octet-stream";
                String extension = url.toString();

                if (extension.endsWith(".mp3"))
                    type = "audio/mp3";
                else if (extension.endsWith(".html"))
                    type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

                response.headers.add("Content-Type: " + type);
            }

            return response;
        }

        private void writeEntity(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = -1;

            while ((read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Response {

        public List<String> headers = new LinkedList<String>();
        public URL url;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this actually fixed the problem and now its playing on the iphone. but i cant move forward/back on this playback, is there a way to improve this server so it will support it? (it works on lamp)

Comment: No. HTTP is the problem here. If you require a protocol for streaming media, look at Adobe RTMP. However once the file is fully downloaded, you can certainly play, pause, skip and fast forward, but it all happens on the client side

Comment: Indeed, a php server is not an http client... so how/why would it connect to this?

Comment: @BaileyS who are you asking? And what, exactly?

Comment: In the question, Dima keeps saying that the code works if he uses a php server... but that does not make any sense.

Comment: Agree. I think he means he can seek the audio file downloaded from an Apache server within its music player. @DimaGoltsman just guessing, but maybe you can measure the MP3 and sent the `Content-Length` header

Comment: i just tried to add content length, didnt help. any other ideas?

Comment: @Raffaele, i mean on a php server i can seek the file, move forward/back at any time

Comment: @DimaGoltsman your comment is misleading. There ain't anything as a *PHP server*, maybe you intend Apache httpd, but PHP doesn't come into the game when you download a file. And the seek happens on the client side, because at the HTTP protocol level, there is no way to skip 3 minutes, 10 seconds and so on, especially because MP3 is compressed, and a program can't tell how many bytes has to skip to jump X seconds ahead without first decoding the stream. Please describe the steps you take in both cases

Comment: sorry, i said php server but what i actually mean is that on any server that i download and run (like apache,lighthttpd, etc...) it works and can skip to any place in the song, but it wont skip on the server you wrote on pastebin, it just plays. i tried to send the Content-Length but there is no change.

Comment: there is some progress, i added 2 headers:
        
        File f=new File(RequestHandler.class.getResource(path.replace("/", "")).getFile());
        
                out.print("Content-Length: " + f.length());
                out.print("\r\n");
                out.print("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
                out.print("\r\n");

now in chrome i can skip to any place in the song, but not on the iphone

Comment: @DimaGoltsman iOS uses HTTP range requests. My tiny server obviously doesn't support partial content, but if you fill like you can certainly implement the feature yourself. [Here is the relevant RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35)

Comment: If the filename has spaces, it throws an error. Otherwise it works fine. Why is that?